# get user profile information from twitter through Access token in php

Tags: php, api, curl, twitter

how to get user profile information from twitter using api in php?I have Consumer key,Consumer secret,Access token,Access token secret.

Comment: Try adding some example code, perhaps outlining what you have tried and where you are seeing errors / unexpected results.

Comment: I am using this 

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?access_token=714502466-m88lvoS87wZ9MSleil469ZhYReVlKYn8MudBHaXl

abd get this result: 
{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50261732/getting-user-info-after-his-login-by-twitter-oauth-2-0-abraham-php-lib